# Different PagerTitleStrip in ViewPager on current page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am using a ViewPager for swipe tabs in my application. The viewpager displays 3 tabs, the current, the previous and the next. Now, I want to make the current tab bigger than the previous and next tab.

Is this possible? Setting the PagerTitleStrip textSize sets the textSize for all 3 tabs.

I think I'll need a custom viewpager layout, but I don't know how to do this.

I want to make 'ROOM 5' bigger and the other 2 small
[image: I want to make 'ROOM 5' bigger and the other 2 small]

Code used right now:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:id="@+id/pager"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".RoomViewActivity" 
    >  


    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip  
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_gravity="top"  
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"  
        android:paddingTop="20dp"  
        android:textColor="#fff" 

        />  


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't individually adjust the size of a particular `TextView` in the `PagerTitleStrip` without adjusting the size of the rest. So, if you want use the `PagerTitleStrip` indicator the best way to adjust that text size is to use a `RelativeSizeSpan`. Here's a quick example of doing that:

```
private CharSequence relativeSizeSpan(CharSequence source, int pos) {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != pos) {
        return source;
    }
    final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(source);
    ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, source.length(), 0);
    return ss;
}

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // In your PagerAdapter
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            return relativeSizeSpan(zero, pos);
        case 1:
            return relativeSizeSpan(one, pos);
        case 2:
            return relativeSizeSpan(two, pos);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Otherwise you might look into copying over the source of the `PagerTitleStrip` to edit it as you see fit or use an alternative third party indicator like [viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Here's a screenshot from the above example using a `RelativeSizeSpan`.

[image: Example]